# Cannot find module 'react-native-safe-area-context'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

i'm learning React Native.
I'm trying to use SafeAreaProvider and SafeAreaView but when i do this :

```js
import { SafeAreaProvider, SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
```

i got the message Cannot find module 'react-native-safe-area-context'

Here are my versions :

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
```

Can you help me ? thank you a lot !

I tried to downgrade  react-native-safe-area-context to 4.5 from 4.7.1

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error message "Cannot find module 'react-native-safe-area-context'" because the SafeAreaContext library is not installed in your environment.

The library is included in Expo Go, but if you're using NPM, you should follow the instructions [here.](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/safe-area-context/)

Run this command in your environment terminal to install the library locally:

```
- npx expo install react-native-safe-area-context
```

If that command doesn't work, try this one instead:

```
npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer but is doesnt work, i again have "cannot find module" 
When i run your command it says
up to date, audited 1270 packages in 6s

63 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

Comment: @Pierre-maxHalldegare I updated my comment. See if my update fixes your issue.